# Silencing OSX crash report window

Tags: python, macos, crash-reports

I have a python application which uses a compiled shared library. This library for some reason crashes with a segfault every time the app throws an exception. OSX catches the segfault somehow and shows a report crash window. How can I shut off this window once and for all ?

Comment: Find a patched version of the library, or use another one. (In an ideal world, of course...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the crash reporter globally, but I don't think there is a way to disable it locally.  This web site has details: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091230100541242.  Basically, you can use /Developer/Applications/Utilities/CrashReporterPrefs if you have XCode installed.  Otherwise, you can use the command line

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType server
```

To disable it entirely.